# Syntax Error in Calculator Program

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-2.x, python-2.4

I wrote this code as a calculator but I am getting a syntax error because I need to define the [add, subtract, etc.] How do I do this?

```
from math import*

def main():
print("Tremelling Enterprises: Calculator s1-1SC  ")
raw_input('What would you like to do?  add, subtract, divide, multiply,         powers, or square roots?')
if == add:
        print("Welcome to the adding department! ")
        print("What are your two values?")
        x = raw_input('What is the value of the first number? ')
        y = raw_input('What is the value of the second number? ')
        solution1 = x + y
        print(solution1)
    if == subtract:
        print("Welcome to the subtracting department! ")
        print("What are your two values?")
        a = raw_input('What is the value of the first number? ')
        b = raw_input('What is the value of the second number? ')
        solution2 = a - b
        print(solution2)
    if == divide:
        print("Welcome to the division department! ")
        print("What are your two values?")
        c = raw_input('What is the value of the first number? ')
        d = raw_input('What is the value of the second number? ')
        solution3 = c / d
        print(solution3)        
    if == multiply:
        print("Welcome to the multiplication department! ")
        print("What are your two values?")
        e = raw_input('What is the value of the first number? ')
        f = raw_input('What is the value of the second number? ')
        solution4 = e * f
        print(solution1)
    if == powers:
        print("Welcome to the power department! ")
        print("What are your two values?")
        g = raw_input('What is the value of the base? ')
        h = raw_input('What is the value of the exponent? ')
        solution5 = pow(g,h)
        print(solution5)
    if == square roots:
        print("Welcome to the square roots department!")
        print("what is your value?")
        i = raw_input('number')
        solution6 = sqrt(i)
        print(solution6)
    else:
        print("Sorry, that function is not availible at this time.")
main()
```

It would be wonderful if this could run and work properly. Thank you

P.S. This is not for a class, but just a fun course Not for any credits.

Comment: Is that your actual indentation? Also what is `if == subtract:` supposed to be doing? You are not comparing to anything so that is one error.  You don't store the output from `raw_input` which I imagine you are supposed to be comparing to in your if statements.

Comment: Posting the actual error would help a lot.

Comment: This isn't just a typo somewhere; your program's syntax is simply wrong. Please check the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: you need to assign your raw input to a variable and compare the variable to actual values.  For example  x = "Hello World"  
You can then do things like
if x == "Hello World":
   print "X was Hello World"

Comment: `if == add` This is wrong on many levels.

Comment: If this is for a class, you should either attend it or open your textbook instead of trying to get people to do your homework for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a homework completion service.

Comment: If you're getting an error, it might be a good idea to..ya know..include the error...

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some hints. You are on the right track. You have two different ways of handling the `raw_input` and one of those approaches is correct. So here are some changes to the first few lines which should get you the rest of the way in short order.

```
def main():
  print("Tremelling Enterprises: Calculator s1-1SC  ")
  action = raw_input('What would you like to do?  add, subtract, divide, multiply,         powers, or square roots?')
  if action == "add":
        print("Welcome to the adding department! ")
        print("What are your two values?")
        x = raw_input('What is the value of the first number? ')
        y = raw_input('What is the value of the second number? ')
        solution1 = x + y
        print(solution1)
```

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the add, subtract,etc. not being indicated. How do I do that?

Comment: Those {add, etc.} are not defined.